# mutate on nested tibble

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr, tibble

I have a nested `tibble` in the following form:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

ex <- tibble(data = list(val = rnorm(12), 
                         val = rnorm(5), 
                         val = rep(NA, 5), 
                         val = c(rnorm(3), NA)), 
               p1 = rnorm(4),
               p2 = rnorm(4)) %>% 
         mutate(data = map(data, tibble))
```

and I would like a new column filled with *p*-values calculated from `ks.test` for each `tibble` in `data` compared to a normal distribution which parameters are stored in `p1` and `p2`.

I tried something like

```
ex %>%
   mutate(ks_test = map(data, 
             ~tryCatch( #to avoid problems with tibbles filled only by NAs
                ks.test(x = .$val,
                        y = "pnorm",
                        mean = .$p1,
                        sd = .$p2), 
              error = function(e) list(p.value = NA))),
           ks_pvalue = map_dbl(ks_test, "p.value"))
```

which unfortunately fails to perform the test, providing only NAs.

Please, can you help me to fix this chunk of code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I will refer you to `purrr::possibly` to handle your NA cases. As far as handling the vectors which are complete it helps to have a grouping column to nest by. Also a specific function for the ks_test helps keep things clean.

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyverse)


val1 = data.frame(val = rnorm(12), group = 1)
val2 = data.frame(val = rnorm(5), group = 2)

ks_test_fun <- function(data, p1, p2, ...){
  data %>% 
  ks.test(x = .$val, y = "pnorm", mean = p1, sd = p2) %>% 
  broom::tidy() %>% 
  pull(p.value)
}

set.seed(4)
rbind(val1, val2) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(p1 = rnorm(2), p2 = rnorm(2)) %>% 
  mutate(ks_test_pval = map(data, ks_test_fun, p1, p2)) %>% 
  unnest(ks_test_pval)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   group data                  p1    p2 ks_test_pval
#>   <dbl> <list>             <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1     1 <tibble [12 x 1]>  0.217 0.891        0.137
#> 2     2 <tibble [5 x 1]>  -0.542 0.596        0.333
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: You can also avoid the `unnest()` on the last line, by using `map_dbl` as opposed to `map` on the previous line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your suggestions about `possibly` and using a specific function to improve code readability. However, the ideal answer should be applied to the object `ex`, provided in the question and it should be able to deal with "all-NAs" tibbles. Thanks.

Comment: @Ndr I wonder if the "all-NAs" is more a matter of data cleaning. To me it seems that ks.test fails in cases were the column is NA-only, but you must have the same number of rows on p1 and p2 as you have non-NA-only tibbles. I would filter out the rows that are NA-only before pushing to ks.test, but maybe this is not an option for you.

Comment: The option of filtering out the NA-only rows is not feasible as I have to preserve all the rows in the original dataset. Maybe, an option would be to use something like an `ifelse` statement for which the NA-only rows (`sum(!is.na(x)) == 0`) will give a `ks_test_pval <- NA`, whereas the rows with `sum(!is.na(x)) != 0` will be submitted to the `ks_test_fun`, however I would need some help to implement it.